# Class array in constructor with reflection

Tags: java

I need to use reflection in my code, so my program doesn't break with every different version. I want to create a new instance of a class and the constructor that I want to use contains an array of a class. But that class also has to be found using reflection. This is an example of what I currently have.

```
Constructor<?> constructor = getClass("className").getConstructor(getClass("anotherClass"));

private Class<?> getClass(String name) {
    return Class.forName("my.package." + version + "." + name);
}
```

However the constructor doesn't use that class, but an array of that class, so how would I turn this class into an array type of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Java Virtual Machine specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-FieldType) specifies the class names for array types. You could construct such a name and use `Class#forName`. However, the logic for the names differs between primitive types and reference types, so it might get annoying generating those `String` names.

Instead, you can construct an array of size 0 for the given type and use it to retrieve its type with `getClass()`.

For example

```
Class<?> componentType = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
Class<?> arrayType = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(componentType, 0).getClass();
System.out.println(arrayType);
```

will print

```
class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

`arrayType` will then hold the `Class` object for the given array type. You can use it to retrieve the constructor.